# Hyperlink to longtabu with numbered equations sends to the end of table

Tags: equations, hyperref, cleveref, longtabu

I have created a long table that spans multiple pages using the `longtabu` environment. Within the table I have an equation on each row which are separately numbered using the `\numberwithin` argument. However, whenever I click on a hyperlink for the table it sends me to the end of the table. I have 
included all the packages that I am using in the document in case there is an issue of conflict between them. It's not a huge issue but is irksome.

```
\documentclass[PhD, plaintoc,lscape]{msu-thesis}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,gensymb,caption,longtable,tabu,tikz,float}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb,url,bm,array,cases,paralist,mathtools,multirow,bbm }
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{natbib,doi}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\setlength{\bibsep}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\setlength{\bibsep}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage{hyperref}
 \bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{;}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={blue!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!70!black}
  }
  \usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\numberwithin{equation}{table}

%\title{Simulation Analyses of Integrated Tagging and Catch-at-Age Analysis Models and Application to Lake Erie Walleye}
%\author{Matthew T. Vincent}
%\fieldofstudy{Fisheries and Wildlife} % This should be in sentence case
%\date{2017}
\begin{document}
Need to have a hyperlink to the table to see issue \cref{tab:Ch1Equations}.

  \clearpage\pagestyle{lscape}
  \begin{landscape}
%\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
  \newcommand*{\SetEqNum}{%
    \refstepcounter{equation}%
    \thetag\theequation
  }
  \begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {X[1,c,m] X[5,c,m,$] }
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\cref{tab:Ch1Equations} (cont'd)} \endhead
  \caption{Equations used to model and estimate population dynamics in Operating and ITCAAN models.} \label{tab:Ch1Equations}\\%[-5ex]
    \toprule 
    Equation Number & \text{Equation}  \\
    \hline 
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:A} & A\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:B} & B\\
       \multicolumn{2}{c}{Abundance and Survival}\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:c} & C\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:d} & D\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:e} & E\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:f} & F\\     
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Fishing Mortality and Effort}\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:g} & G\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:h} & H\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:i} & I\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:j} & J\\ 
     \multicolumn{2}{c}{Survey Calculations}\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:k} & K\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:l} & L\\
     \multicolumn{2}{c}{Movement Estimation}\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:m} & M\\
     \multicolumn{2}{c}{Tag Dynamics}\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:n} & N\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:o} & O\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:p} & P\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:q} & Q\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:r} & R\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:s} & S\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:t} & T\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:u} & U\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:v} & V\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:w} & W\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:x} & X\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:y} & Y\\
     \multicolumn{2}{c}{Initial Abundance Estimation}\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:z} & Z\\
     \multicolumn{2}{c}{Catch Calculations}\\    
    \SetEqNum\label{eq:aa} & AA\\ 
    \SetEqNum\label{eq:bb} & BB\\
    \SetEqNum\label{eq:cc} & CC\\   
    \bottomrule 
\end{longtabu}
\end{landscape}
\pagestyle{plain}

Need to have a hyperlink to the table to see issue \cref{tab:Ch1Equations}
\end{document}
```

Here is a list of the packages used in the final document and their versions

```
 msu-thesis.cls    2017/08/17 Michigan State University Thesis Class version 2.8 TESTING-CHAPTERBIB-V2
  memoir.cls    2016/05/16 v3.7f configurable book, report, article document class
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
  ifetex.sty    2011/12/15 v1.2 ifetex
  ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
  ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
    mem12.clo    2010/10/19 v0.4b memoir class 12pt size option
  mempatch.sty    2009/07/24 v6.0f Patches for memoir class v1.6180339
  etoolbox.sty    2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
  pdflscape.sty    2016/05/14 v0.11 Display of landscape pages in PDF (HO)
   lscape.sty    2000/10/22 v3.01 Landscape Pages (DPC)
  graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
  graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
   pdftex.def    2017/06/24 v1.0g Graphics/color driver for pdftex
     tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
      pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
   pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
  everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
   pgfrcs.code.tex
  pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
  graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
   keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
   pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
   pgfsys.code.tex
  pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
  pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pgfcore.code.tex
  pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
   pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
   pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
  pgfkeys.sty    
  pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgfmath.sty    
  pgfmath.code.tex
   pgffor.code.tex
     tikz.code.tex
  inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
     utf8.def    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
    t1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   ot1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   omsenc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
  fontenc.sty
    t1enc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
  newtxtext.sty    2017/05/28 v1.523
  fontaxes.sty    2014/03/23 v1.0d Font selection axes
   xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
   xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
  fontenc.sty
    t1enc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
  textcomp.sty    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
   ts1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
  newtxmath.sty    2017/05/31 v1.524
  amsmath.sty    2016/11/05 v2.16a AMS math features
  amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
   amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
   amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
   amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
   binhex.tex
  gensymb.sty    2003/07/02 v1.0 (WaS)
  amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
  amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
    url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
   bm.sty    2017/01/16 v1.2c Bold Symbol Support (DPC/FMi)
  cases.sty    2002/05/02 ver 2.5 
  paralist.sty    2017/01/22 v2.7 Extended list environments
  mathtools.sty    2017/05/24 v1.19 mathematical typesetting tools
     calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  mhsetup.sty    2017/03/31 v1.3 programming setup (MH)
  multirow.sty    2016/11/25 v2.2 Span multiple rows of a table
      bbm.sty    1999/03/15 V 1.2 provides fonts for set symbols - TH
  caption.sty    2016/02/21 v3.3-144 Customizing captions (AR)
  caption3.sty    2016/05/22 v1.7-166 caption3 kernel (AR)
  longtable.sty    2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
     tabu.sty    2011/02/26 v2.8 - flexible LaTeX tabulars (FC)
  varwidth.sty    2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
    float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
  chapterbib.sty    2010/09/18  v 1.17
  enumitem.sty    2011/09/28 v3.5.2 Customized lists
   natbib.sty    2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
      doi.sty    2007/07/24 handle doi numbers
  hyperref.sty    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hypertext links for LaTeX
  hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
  hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
   hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
  infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
  ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
  intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
  etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
  kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
  kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
  pdftexcmds.sty    2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
  pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
  bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
  uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
  letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
  hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
  xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
  atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
  atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
  refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
  hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
  auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
  kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
   pd1enc.def    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
  hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
  memhfixc.sty    2013/05/30 v1.17 nameref/hyperref package fixes for memoir 
class
  hpdftex.def    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
  rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
  bookmark.sty    2016/05/17 v1.26 PDF bookmarks (HO)
  bkm-pdftex.def    2016/05/17 v1.26 bookmark driver for pdfTeX (HO)
  cleveref.sty    2013/12/28 v0.19 Intelligent cross-referencing
  t1ntxtlf.fd    2015/01/17 v1.0 font definition file for T1/ntx/tlf
  omlntxmi.fd    2015/08/25 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OML/ntxmi.
  untxexa.fd    2012/04/16 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxexa.
   ts1cmr.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
  lmsntxsy.fd    2016/07/02 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for LMS/ntxsy.
  lmxntxexx.fd    2016/07/03 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for LMX/ntxexx.supp-pdf.mkii
  epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
   grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
  ltcaption.sty    2013/06/09 v1.4-94 longtable captions (AR)
  nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
  gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
  ot1ntxtlf.fd    2015/01/17 v1.0 font definition file for OT1/ntx/tlf
  untxmia.fd    2016/01/31 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxmia.
  untxsym.fd    2015/03/20 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxsym.
  untxsyc.fd    2012/04/12 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxsyc.
   umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
   umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
  ts1ntxtlf.fd    2015/01/18 v1.0 fd file for TS1/ntxtlf
```

Comment: it is in TeXlive and Miktex releases   
https://www.ctan.org/pkg/msu-thesis?lang=en

Comment: @user3653085: The hyper anchor of the label  is set to the end of the table, use `\caption{Equations used to model and estimate population dynamics in Operating and ITCAAN models.} \phantomsection\label{tab:Ch1Equations}\\` instead, i.e. place an explicit `\phantomsection` and its associated anchor

Answer (score 2):

Usually the option `hypcap` of package `caption` moves the anchor to the heading of table or image:

```
\captionsetup{hypcap=true} % <==========================================
```

But `tabu` is the problem here, it is not compatible with that.  Therefore you have to set the anchor by yourself with `\phantomsection` like:

```
\caption{Equations used to model and estimate population dynamics in Operating and ITCAAN models.} \phantomsection\label{tab:Ch1Equations}\\
%                                                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the following MWE

```
\documentclass[PhD, plaintoc,lscape]{msu-thesis}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,gensymb,caption,longtable,tabu,tikz,float}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb,url,bm,array,cases,paralist,mathtools,multirow,bbm }
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{natbib,doi}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\setlength{\bibsep}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\captionsetup{hypcap=true} % <==========================================
 \bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{;}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={blue!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!70!black}
  }
  \usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\numberwithin{equation}{table}

%\title{Simulation Analyses of Integrated Tagging and Catch-at-Age Analysis Models and Application to Lake Erie Walleye}
%\author{Matthew T. Vincent}
%\fieldofstudy{Fisheries and Wildlife} % This should be in sentence case
%\date{2017}
\begin{document}
Need to have a hyperlink to the table to see issue \cref{tab:Ch1Equations}.

  \clearpage\pagestyle{lscape}
  \begin{landscape}
%\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
  \newcommand*{\SetEqNum}{%
    \refstepcounter{equation}%
    \thetag\theequation
  }
  \begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {X[1,c,m] X[5,c,m,$] }
    \caption{Equations used to model and estimate population dynamics in Operating and ITCAAN models.} \phantomsection\label{tab:Ch1Equations}\\%[-5ex] % <=====================
    \toprule 
    Equation Number & \text{Equation}  \\
    \midrule 
\endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\cref{tab:Ch1Equations} (cont'd)}
    %\toprule 
    %Equation Number & \text{Equation}  \\
    %\midrule
 \endhead
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:A} & A\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:B} & B\\
       \multicolumn{2}{c}{Abundance and Survival}\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:c} & C\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:d} & D\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:e} & E\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:f} & F\\     
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Fishing Mortality and Effort}\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:g} & G\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:h} & H\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:i} & I\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:j} & J\\ 
     \multicolumn{2}{c}{Survey Calculations}\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:k} & K\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:l} & L\\
     \multicolumn{2}{c}{Movement Estimation}\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:m} & M\\
     \multicolumn{2}{c}{Tag Dynamics}\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:n} & N\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:o} & O\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:p} & P\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:q} & Q\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:r} & R\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:s} & S\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:t} & T\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:u} & U\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:v} & V\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:w} & W\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:x} & X\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:y} & Y\\
     \multicolumn{2}{c}{Initial Abundance Estimation}\\
     \SetEqNum\label{eq:z} & Z\\
     \multicolumn{2}{c}{Catch Calculations}\\    
    \SetEqNum\label{eq:aa} & AA\\ 
    \SetEqNum\label{eq:bb} & BB\\
    \SetEqNum\label{eq:cc} & CC\\   
    \bottomrule 
\end{longtabu}
\end{landscape}
\pagestyle{plain}

Need to have a hyperlink to the table to see issue \cref{tab:Ch1Equations}
\end{document}
```

and the resulting pages after clicking the link:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Here is the list of used packages and version numbers on my computer:

```
 *File List*
msu-thesis.cls    2017/06/22 Michigan State University Thesis Class version 2.7
  memoir.cls    2016/05/16 v3.7f configurable book, report, article document class
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
  ifetex.sty    2011/12/15 v1.2 ifetex
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   mem12.clo    2010/10/19 v0.4b memoir class 12pt size option
mempatch.sty    2009/07/24 v6.0f Patches for memoir class v1.6180339
pdflscape.sty    2016/05/14 v0.11 Display of landscape pages in PDF (HO)
  lscape.sty    2000/10/22 v3.01 Landscape Pages (DPC)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2017/06/24 v1.0g Graphics/color driver for pdftex
etoolbox.sty    2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
newtxtext.sty    2017/05/28 v1.523
fontaxes.sty    2014/03/23 v1.0d Font selection axes
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
textcomp.sty    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
  ts1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
newtxmath.sty    2017/05/31 v1.524
 amsmath.sty    2016/11/05 v2.16a AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
  binhex.tex
 gensymb.sty    2003/07/02 v1.0 (WaS)
 caption.sty    2016/02/21 v3.3-144 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2016/05/22 v1.7-166 caption3 kernel (AR)
longtable.sty    2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
    tabu.sty    2011/02/26 v2.8 - flexible LaTeX tabulars (FC)
varwidth.sty    2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
      bm.sty    2017/01/16 v1.2c Bold Symbol Support (DPC/FMi)
   cases.sty    2002/05/02 ver 2.5 
paralist.sty    2017/01/22 v2.7 Extended list environments
mathtools.sty    2017/05/24 v1.19 mathematical typesetting tools
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 mhsetup.sty    2017/03/31 v1.3 programming setup (MH)
multirow.sty    2016/11/25 v2.2 Span multiple rows of a table
     bbm.sty    1999/03/15 V 1.2 provides fonts for set symbols - TH
chapterbib.sty    2010/09/18  v 1.17
enumitem.sty    2011/09/28 v3.5.2 Customized lists
  natbib.sty    2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
     doi.sty    2007/07/24 handle doi numbers
hyperref.sty    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
memhfixc.sty    2013/05/30 v1.17 nameref/hyperref package fixes for memoir class
 hpdftex.def    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
bookmark.sty    2016/05/17 v1.26 PDF bookmarks (HO)
bkm-pdftex.def    2016/05/17 v1.26 bookmark driver for pdfTeX (HO)
cleveref.sty    2013/12/28 v0.19 Intelligent cross-referencing
t1ntxtlf.fd    2015/01/17 v1.0 font definition file for T1/ntx/tlf
omlntxmi.fd    2015/08/25 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OML/ntxmi.
 untxexa.fd    2012/04/16 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxexa.
  ts1cmr.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
lmsntxsy.fd    2016/07/02 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for LMS/ntxsy.
lmxntxexx.fd    2016/07/03 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for LMX/ntxexx.
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
ltcaption.sty    2013/06/09 v1.4-94 longtable captions (AR)
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
ot1ntxtlf.fd    2015/01/17 v1.0 font definition file for OT1/ntx/tlf
 untxmia.fd    2016/01/31 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxmia.
 untxsym.fd    2015/03/20 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxsym.
 untxsyc.fd    2012/04/12 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxsyc.
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
ts1ntxtlf.fd    2015/01/18 v1.0 fd file for TS1/ntxtlf
 ***********
```

Comment: I tried using this fix in the full document and the links for the table now go to the beginning of the document

Comment: @user3653085  Which TeX distribution do you use and which version numbers of your used packages.  Please add command `\listfiles` before `\documentclass ...`, compile and check the resulting log file. At the end of log file you will find the list of used packages and version numbers. Add this list to your question please ...

Comment: The new version is still in beta testing and I told the developer that I would not share the current copy I have with anyone. I tested using the version that you have and the result was the same.  When I tested your fix I did it for the full document from which I created the MWE. I do not think that the issue is the version of msu-thesis.cls. I think there is something else in the full document that is conflicting that I did not include in the MWE. The answer that you provided does solve the issue for the MWE.

Comment: I realized that the only references I have to the table is the  ones in the table itself (i.e., on the second and third page) and in the `\listoftables` . The link in the table itself goes to the top of the table as expected. However, the link in the list of tables goes to the last equation in the table whether or not I include the `\phantomsection` .